# Building a recursive string function

Tags: boolean

I am trying to build a function whose output is a list of all possible boolean expressions with an upper bound. For three variables p,q and r my function would be, theoretically:

f(0) = {p,q,r} // this notation refer to the mathematical set such that p,q and r belong to f(0).
f(n+1) = { (A & B) such that A and B belongs to f(n) } Union { (A or B) such that A and B belongs to f(n) } Union { (not A) such that A belongs to f(n) }
I want to receive a matrix whose rows are the strings of all the possible strings corresponding to boolean formulas build by n iterations of the function. For example:

```
f(2)=['p' ; 'q' ; 'r' ; '(p&q)' ; 'p&(p or q)' ; 'r or (p & r)' ; ... ]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a site about *specific* programming questions. If you have one of those and can't figure it out by other means, we are happy to help but we are not here to write your code for you.

Comment: Thank you for the greetings, but you don't need to explain me the reason why you are here! I just assumed that maybe someone would like the challenge, just for the fun of it.